# TTS and Music simultaneously on iOS7?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, text-to-speech

I'm wondering if its possible to have music playback and some kind of text-to-speech engine to work simultaneously on iOS7. I'm using the new built in API from Apple and either one is working, not both. Any idea someone?
My TTS playback code, also working in background

```
 -(void)speak:(NSString*)string
{
   AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

   NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
   [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];

   NSError *activationError = nil;
   [audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationError];

   AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:string];
   utterance.rate = 0.3f;
   utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:[AVSpeechSynthesisVoice currentLanguageCode]];

   AVSpeechSynthesizer *synth = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
   [synth speakUtterance:utterance];

}
```

Comment: I am having the same issue but not sure your solution works for me.  I want to have the iPod playing in the background and I want to have the AVSpeechUtterance library interrupt the iPod and say what it needs to say and have the iPod continue to play.  My AVSpeechUtterance code looks exactly as yours does.  Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: updated my answer to what I'am actually using and is working as desired. The second parameter withOptions was the key...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, found it myself reading the docs.

Using

```
BOOL success = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
  withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:&setCategoryError];
```

does mix audio playback with the tts engine.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for posting I will try this out.  I actually posted a question about this topic a couple of days ago, but no one has had any answers or suggestions.  I posted a full description of my code.  Could you check it out and see if what I am doing correlates to how you are using audioSessions in your project?  The thread is found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403331/avaudiosession-mixing-with-avspeechutterance